# ¿Como agregar un archivo XML a un campo en una tabla de sql server?

Tags: sql-server

trabajo sombre una base de datos donde es necesario guardar un archivo XML generado por un webService, mi pregunta es, ¿como deberia guardarlo? ¿con que formato? muchas gracias de antemano :)
Todo el codigo de back-end esta desarrollado en c# asp.net.

Comment: Agrega más detalles, como por ejemplo. ¿En qué lenguaje estás desarrollando?

Comment: gracias por el consejo :D y pues estoy desarrollando en c# con asp.net

Comment: No se puede responder con propiedad tu pregunta sin saber: ¿para qué vas a utilizar la información contenida en el XML? y quizás hasta ¿qué tipo de información contiene el XML?

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Por favor, añade la información que te indican dentro de la pregunta, [editándola](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/384569/edit) usando el enlace **editar** bajo la pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al ser un archivo XML, lo normal es que sea un archivo de text normal, puedes crear una tabla con 2 campos, NombreArchivo, contenido y guardar el contenido directamente en la tabla pero si los archivos XML son de gran tamaño lo mejor seria crear una tabla en la que guardes la referencia de en que carpeta se encuentra el archivo.